# AutoResizing Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, autoresizingmask

I added a `UIImageview` as a `subview` of `UITableViewCell.contentview`. It has margins in left and right side of the cell. when rotating device, `Autoresizing` is not working for me. I am using:

```
UIImageView *imgviewcellBg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 3,     self.view.bounds.size.width-18, 33)];
imgviewcellBg.autoresizesSubviews=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgviewcellBg];
```

Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier]autorelease];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, tblMyWines.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    }

    UIImageView *imgviewcellBg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tbl.frame.origin.x+5, 3, tbl.frame.size.width-10.0, 33)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgviewcellBg];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hai Thanks bro. But I am asking about autoresizing when we rotate screen

Comment: If you are going to set this then there is no need of autoresizing as well. Also you needs o set autoresizingMask instead of autoresizesSubviews. Try it & let me know your feedback.

Comment: Now am using autoresizingMask. careless mistake.  Thank you bro.

Comment: So try it & let me know your feedback, it may solve your problem.

Comment: Fine now. My code is working fine. I will try your logic in future. Thanks.

Comment: what you are doing for it?

Comment: UIImageView *imgviewcellBg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 3,Mytblview.bounds.size.width-18, 33)];
imgviewcellBg.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgviewcellBg];